# Example in which a normal subgroup acts non-equivalent on its orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting on $\Delta$, and $H$ be a group acting on $\Gamma$. If there exists an isomorphism $\varphi : G \to H$ and a bijection $\psi : \Delta \to \Gamma$ such that
$$
 \psi( \alpha^g ) = \psi(\alpha)^{\varphi(g)}
$$
for all $\alpha \in \psi, g \in G$ then the two group actions are said to be *permutation isomorphic*, i.e. the representations in the symmetric groups on $\Delta$ and $\Gamma$ are isomorphic as subgroups of the symmetric groups, and under the bijection $\psi$ corresponding elements induce the same cycles. Now they are called *equivalent* iff $G = H$ and $\varphi = \mbox{id}_G$, i.e. if $G$ acts on two sets $\Delta$ and $\Gamma$ and we have a bijection $\psi : \Delta \to \Gamma$ such that
$$
 \psi(\alpha^g) = \psi(\alpha)^g.
$$
Now let $G$ act transitively on $\Omega$ and suppose $N \unlhd G$. Then some orbit $\alpha^N$ forms a [block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(permutation_group_theory)), as if $\beta^g = \gamma$ with $\beta, \gamma \in \alpha^N$ as $(\beta^n)^g = \beta^{gn'} = \gamma^n \in \alpha^N$
and $\beta^N = \alpha^N$, hence $(\alpha^N)^g \subseteq \alpha^N$. Now let $N$ be intransitive, and suppose $\Delta$ and $\Gamma$ are two orbits of $N$. As $G$ acts transitive we have $\Delta = \Gamma^g$ for some $g \in G$. Then $N$ acts on $\Delta$ and $\Gamma$ permutation isomorphic. For the isomorphism we have $\varphi : N \to N$ by $\varphi(n) = n^g$, and the bijection is $\psi(\alpha) = \alpha^g$. Then
$$
 \psi(\alpha^n) = \alpha^{ng} = \alpha^{gn^g} = \psi(\alpha)^{\varphi(n)}.
$$
But in general the actions on the blocks are not equivalent. I am looking for examples where the actions of a normal subgroup on different blocks are indeed not equivalent? If $G$ is abelian, then the above map $\varphi : N \to N$ is the identity map, so $G$ must be non-abelian. An artificial example that comes to my mind is, if $A$ is some group with two nonequivalent transitive actions on two sets $\Delta_1, \Delta_2$, and $t$ is some involution mapping $\Delta_1$ onto $\Delta_2$, then $A \times \langle t \rangle$ acts on $\Delta = \Delta_1 \cup \Delta_2$ by the definition $\alpha^{nt} = (\alpha^n)^t$, which is well-defined as $nt = tn$ (or which could be easily seen by using the external direct product). Then $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are two orbits of $A$ with inequivalent actions. But this example is an ad hoc construction.

> So do you know any (preferable more natural) examples where a normal subgroup acts non-equivalent on its orbits?

**EDIT**: Derek's answer made me think about the kernels of representations. And I guess we have: If $G$ acts on $\Delta$ and $\Gamma$ and $\rho: G \to S_{\Delta}$ and $\sigma : G \to S_{\Gamma}$ are the permutation representations. Then:

i) If $G$ acts equivalent on $\Delta$ and $\Gamma$ then $\mbox{ker}(\rho) = \mbox{ker}(\sigma)$ and $G / \mbox{ker}(\rho)$ acts equivalent, or which says the same
$$
 \psi(\alpha^{\rho(g)}) = \psi(\alpha)^{\sigma(g)}.
$$

If $G$ acts equivalent, then
$$
 g \in \mbox{ker}(\rho)
 \Leftrightarrow \forall \alpha : \alpha^g = \alpha 
 \Leftrightarrow \forall \alpha : \psi(\alpha^g) = \psi(\alpha)
 \Leftrightarrow \forall \alpha : \psi(\alpha)^g = \psi(\alpha) 
 \Leftrightarrow \forall g \in \mbox{ker}(\sigma)
$$
and $\psi(\alpha^{\rho(g)}) = \psi(\alpha^g) = \psi(\alpha)^g = \psi(\alpha)^{\sigma(g)}$. If the above conditions are fulfilled, it is also easily seen that we can define two equivalent actions by $\alpha^g := \varphi^{\rho(g)}$ and $\psi(\alpha)^g := \psi(\alpha)^{\sigma(g)}$.

ii) If $G$ acts permutation isomorphic then $\mbox{ker}(\rho) \cong \mbox{ker}(\sigma)$ and the images act permutation isomorphic. 
Let $G$ act permutation isomorphic, a simple calculation shows $g \in \mbox{ker}(\rho) \Leftrightarrow \varphi(g) \in \mbox{ker}(\sigma)$, hence they are isomorphic by $\varphi$. Further $\varphi$ induces an isomorphism on the images by setting $\overline \varphi(\rho(g)) := \sigma(\varphi(g))$. This is well-defines, as if $\rho(g) = \rho(h)$, then
\begin{align*}
 \psi(\alpha)^{\sigma(\varphi(g)} & = \psi(\alpha)^{\varphi(g)} \\
 & = \psi(\alpha^g) \\ & = \psi(\alpha^{\rho(g)}) = \psi(\alpha^{\rho(h)}) = \psi(\alpha^h) = \psi(\alpha)^{\varphi(h)}
 = \psi(\alpha)^{\sigma(\varphi(h)}.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
 \varphi(\alpha^{\rho(g)}) & = \varphi(\alpha^g) \\
                           & = \varphi(\alpha)^{\varphi(g)} \\
                           & = \varphi(\alpha)^{\sigma(\varphi(g))} \\
                           & = \varphi(\alpha)^{\overline \varphi(\rho(g))}.
\end{align*}
But if it is possible to conversely built up two permutation isomorphic actions from those conditions I do not know yet, as in general $G/N \cong H/M$ with $N\cong M$ does not imply $G \cong H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a small example in one of your recent questions: $A_4$ acting transitively on $6$ points, with $|N|=4$. Then $N$ has three orbits of length $2$ with different kernels on each of the orbits.

Comment: Yes, thank you! This action could be described as the action of $A_4$ on the subsets containing two points. Then $\{1,2\}^N = \{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$, $\{1,3\}^N = \{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$ and $\{2,3\}^N = \{\{2,3\}, \{1,4\}\}$. And for example the first two actions of $N$ on its orbits have kernels $\{(),(12)(34)\}$ and $\{(), (13)(24)\}$.